# Why does Today Widget show 'Unable to load' on iOS 14 and cannot be debugged?

Tags: ios, xcode, widget, ios14, ios10-today-widget

When running my iOS 12+ App on iOS 14 the (long existing) Today Widget does not work any more. Instead of the widget content only `Unable to load` is shown.

The very same code runs without any problem on iOS 13 and below.

**Note:** This is **NOT** about the new Homescreen Widgets introduced with iOS 14. They work fine. This is about the *old* today widgets.

I found several existing threads and other resources about the `Unable to load` issue. However, they are all older and not related to iOS 14. In pretty much all cases the problem was, that the widget crashed and could thus not be loaded.

I tried to debug the widget extension by running it directly from Xcode: Selecting the Widget target instead of the App target and run the project. This works fine on iOS 13 and below. The widgets becomes visible and works as expected. Additionally I can use breakpoints, etc. to check if there is any problem.

On iOS 14 however, nothing happens when I start debugging, expect that Xcode shows `Running com.apple.springboard on iPhone XYZ`. When I switch to the today screen manually the widget is shows as `Unable to load` again.

Since debugging does not work I added a method which **logs messages** to a file in the apps group folder. While this also works fine on iOS 13 and below, it does nothing on iOS 14.

I am working with Xcode 12.1 and as far as I can tell both iOS 14 and 14.1 are affected.

**Is seems that the Widget does not run at all on iOS 14.**

**Any idea what the problem might be? Any idea how find the source of the issue without debugging or logging?**

Comment: same issue. any updates?

Comment: One thing I noticed while debugging the issue, if I removed all the frameworks dependencies, then the Today widget started working again. Seems like there's a crash regarding a framework that I'm still figuring out.

Answer (score 3):

No idea about the cause but I've just updated to 14.2 and none of the non-Apple widgets will run (all show "Unable to load" or blank black widget. And most of those apps have widgets updated for iOS 14.

Comment: Your post shares that you experienced the same issue but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Just trying to point out that there is likely some change in the OS that has "blown away" lots of 3rd party (non-Apple) widgets - in my experience all non-Apple widgets. So either there is some new requirement on widgets or an issue with iOS.